# how to use @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, qualifiers

I want use WebServiceTemplate object from one of the component class but declared in two Configuration classes, below is code

```
@Configuration
public class EddClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate eddTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2EprsMarshaller) {
        ........  
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ProposalClientConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate ProposalTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2EprsMarshaller) {
        ........
        
    }
}

@Component
public class ProposalDataClientImpl implements  ProposalDataClient{
......
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate eddTemplate;
......
}
```

Error is

> Parameter 0 of method eddTemplate in EddClientConfig required a single
> bean, but 2 were found:
> - jaxb2EddMarshaller: defined by method 'jaxb2EddMarshaller' in class path resource [....EddClientConfig.class]
> - jaxb2PropposalDataMarshaller: defined by method 'jaxb2PropposalDataMarshaller' in class path resource
> [...../ProposalDataClientConfig.class]

My Gradle.build file

```
dependencies {
compile(project(':edd-connector')) // EddClientConfig class exists here
compile(project(':proposal-connector')) //ProposalClientConfig class exists here
......
}
```

> What I tried

```
@Configuration
public class EddClientConfig {
    @Bean(name = "eddTemplate")
    public WebServiceTemplate eddTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2EprsMarshaller) {
        ........  
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ProposalClientConfig {
    
    @Bean(name = "ProposalTemplate")
    public WebServiceTemplate ProposalTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2EprsMarshaller) {
        ........     
    }
}

@Component
public class ProposalDataClientImpl implements  ProposalDataClient{
......
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ProposalTemplate")
    private WebServiceTemplate eddTemplate;
......
}
```

But no luck. Just let me know what I did wrong. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Are there 2 `Jaxb2Marshaller` beans available ? Are the bean names mentioned in the console ?

Comment: I agree with @SKumar, its `Jaxb2Marshaller` that probably has 2 implementations and Spring doesn't know which one to inject, the problem probably is not in your beans Try to find this `Jaxb2Marshaller`. also share your `pom.xml` probably a dependency there brings the extra implementation or have you defined it with `@Beans` somewhere and how?

Comment: @SKumar, Yes 2 Jaxb2Marshller beans available in two different modules, I need two modules, so I compile both in my build gradle file. So Ambiguity is happening. Kindly let me know how to solve this error.

Comment: @pleft, thanks for your comment. I attached my gradle file and full error.

Comment: @kodali Please post the full code of the configuration classes `ProposalClientConfig`  and `EddClientConfig`

Comment: Do you have control over those 2 sub modules ? Can you change them ?

Comment: Share the code where you create both `Jaxb2Marshaller` beans!

Comment: Yes, I have control over those 2 sub modules, I can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Parameter 0 of method eddTemplate in EddClientConfig required a single
> bean, but 2 were found:
>
> - jaxb2EddMarshaller: defined by method 'jaxb2EddMarshaller' in class path resource [....EddClientConfig.class]
> - jaxb2PropposalDataMarshaller: defined by method 'jaxb2PropposalDataMarshaller' in class path resource
>   [...../ProposalDataClientConfig.class]

This exception should go away if you use `Qualifier` with a bean name, just how you tried in `ProposalDataClientImpl`. Since, there are 2 beans - `jaxb2EddMarshaller` and `jaxb2PropposalDataMarshaller`. We can use them like below so that Spring would know that `eddTemplate` should use `jaxb2EddMarshaller` and the other config the other `Marshaller` -

```
@Configuration
public class EddClientConfig {
    @Bean(name = "eddTemplate")
    public WebServiceTemplate eddTemplate(@Qualifier("jaxb2EddMarshaller")Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2EprsMarshaller) {
        ........  
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ProposalClientConfig {

    @Bean(name = "ProposalTemplate")
    public WebServiceTemplate ProposalTemplate(@Qualifier("jaxb2PropposalDataMarshaller")Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2EprsMarshaller) {
        ........     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Parameter 0 of method eddTemplate in EddClientConfig required a single
> bean, but 2 were found

```
@Configuration
public class EddClientConfig {
    // this is the method in the trace
    @Bean(name = "eddTemplate")
    // parameter 0 = jaxb2EprsMarshaller --> there are 2 impl of this bean in your app context
    public WebServiceTemplate eddTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2EprsMarshaller) {
        
    }
}
```

You need to see where these beans are created in your autoconfiguration or create your own bean of type `Jaxb2Marshaller` and use that.

Comment: Yes you right. I have two beans which are coming from two modules which I am importing modules. Please let me know how to specify I need particular implementation only.

Comment: Find out what the bean is and add a `@Qualifier("bean name")` in the method signature like @SKumar suggested

Comment: This comment useful.

Comment: thank you - please accept if this is sufficient or lmk if you have more questions

Comment: SKumar answer enough for me.